# ¿Puedo acceder a objetos implicitamente o anonima en c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, objeto, class

Tengo varios objetos creados de una clase, y quiero acceder a sus propiedades, pero al ser varios objetos me gustaría poder ingresar a un objeto sin especificar su nombre por código, es decir, tener los nombres de los objetos almacenados en una lista o una variable y acceder a ellos implícitamente,

algo como esto:

```
MyClass Class1 = new MyClass();

string Object = "Class1";

string ObjectValue = MyClass(Object).value;
```

---

y no esto:

```
MyClass Class1 = new MyClass();

string ObjectName = Class1.value;
```

---

¿Hay alguna forma de poder hacerlo?

Comment: Lo más cercano que tienes es Reflection. Pero no será tan simple como el código que muestras.

Comment: Puedes crear instancias de objecto por el nombre de la clase con este metodo: Activator.CreateInstance, pero al parecer solo aplica para .net 6, revisa la documentacion oficial de microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#overloads

Comment: Podrias tener una clase factory que cree objetos dynamic de diferentes tipos.. no veo un escenario donde esto sea necesario, nunca....

Comment: Creo que lo solucione, hice algo parecido, no creé los objetos tal cual en tiempo de ejecucion, pero si cree un array de objetos de la misma clase que contiene todos los objetos que quiero utilizar, y solo tengo que indicar la posición del objeto y el método que usaré.

Answer (score 0):

Atendiendo a tus explicaciones podría proponerte trabajar con diccionarios:

```
Dictionary<string, MyClass> diccClases = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();

diccClases["Class1"] = new MyClass();
diccClases["Class2"] = new MyClass();
diccClases["ClassN"] = new MyClass();
```

El tipo de datos **Dictionary** es de los que se conoce como **llave-valor**, donde la llave es única y tiene asociado un valor. En este caso especifico declaramos un diccionario donde la llave es un **string** y el valor es de tipo **MyClass**, y por  cada llave instanciamos objetos de tipo **MyClass**.

Para acceder a determinado objeto a través de su llave haríamos:

```
diccClases["Class1"].MetodoX();
```

De esta forma accedemos al objeto que se almacenó en el diccionario con la **llave "Class1"**.

También podríamos hacer:

```
var obj = diccClases["Class1"];

obj.MetodoX();
```

Guardamos en la **variable obj** el objeto cuya llave es **"Class1"** y después accedemos a cualquier método o propiedad del mismo.